# C++ : overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

Tags: c++, c++11

```
long long sum;
sum=pow(10,19);
cout<<sum;
```

Above code in **C++** gives the error:

> overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

While following code runs fine:

```
long long sum;
sum=pow(10,18);
cout<<sum;
```

What might be the issue ?

Comment: 10 to the 19'th power is a **really big** number...

Comment: _"What might be the issue ?"_ The second number parameter obviously.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `long long`is too small to hold the result of `pow(10,19)`.

`long long` is usually 64 bits, and a 64 bit integer can hold approx. 1.8*10^19 different values. However, since it is signed, you only get the half of it (the other half is for negative values). And the half of that is 0.9*10^19, which is apparently less than 10^19.

Another issue (but not the reason of the warning / overflow) here is that the `pow()` function returns a floating-point value. So even if the result would fit into `long long` - which it does not - you might loose some precision and not get the exact integer result.

Edit: Of course, you could use `unsigned long long` for this case instead. That would be enough for 10^19, but not for 10^20. So you are just defering the problem to a later time when you are using similarily large numbers that don't fit into `unsigned long long`.

Comment: So if I want to use the result of something like 10^100, how should I store that ?

Comment: You should store it as a floating-point value, e.g. `float`, `double` or `long double`, depending on the version of [pow()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) that you are using.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Or [boost multi-precision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html). I find it extremely easy to use (at least the arbitrarily long integer part, see e.g. the example on the end of the page [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html)).

Comment: @vsoftco - there are multiple options, sure. My point was merely, "when the basic types are not enough, use an arbitrary precision library" and I just gave one example.

Answer (score 5):

```
log2(10^18) ~ 59.80
log2(10^19) ~ 63.12
```

A signed `long long` is likely to be 64bit with 1bit reserved for the sign, thus 10^18 nicely fits, but 10^19 doesnt.

The C++ standard also only gurantees that numbers up to `2^63-1` can be stored in a `long long`.

`pow` is also operating on floating points. Its result will not be exact. Therefore saving it to an integer is likely a mistake anyway.

Answer (score 3):

long long max value is only 9223372036854 775 807
and pow(10,19) is bigger number 10000000000000000000